# On Topic: Questions about effectiveness of equipment

Tags: discussion, scope

I am looking for information on equipment specifically what works and what doesn't eg. does TRX work. I can read reviews but in general I find that SE gives better answers. I know how to ask in that I have specific goals etc. The problem is that I am concerned this may lead to opinion answers. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Include specific context around your situation: how well it works *for what*. Also enrich "works" into something that reflects the complexity of everything fitness. For example, asking for pros and cons of a particular tool (ie TRX) applied to your specific situation and constraints.